# Flashlist is not scrolling while using GestureHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

THE ISSUE IS ONLY ON ANDROID

Flashlist is not scrolling when I wrap the List component to BottomSheet component, However when I comment out the BottomSheet component it works fine. So the issue is related to the BottomSheet component.

The List component itself is been rendered inside a flashlist, This is how I'm using it

```
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{  height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute' }}>
                            <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: '100%', width: '100%', }}>
                                <BottomSheet ref={ref}>
                                    <List />
                                </BottomSheet>
                            </View>
 </GestureHandlerRootView>
```

BottomSheet component:

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  Extrapolate,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');

const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 50;

type BottomSheetProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export type BottomSheetRefProps = {
  scrollTo: (destination: number) => void;
  isActive: () => boolean;
};

const BottomSheet = React.forwardRef<BottomSheetRefProps, BottomSheetProps>(
  ({ children }, ref) => {
    const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
    const active = useSharedValue(false);

    const scrollTo = useCallback((destination: number) => {
      'worklet';
      active.value = destination !== 0;

      translateY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
    }, []);

    const isActive = useCallback(() => {
      return active.value;
    }, []);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ scrollTo, isActive }), [
      scrollTo,
      isActive,
    ]);

    const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
      .onStart(() => {
        context.value = { y: translateY.value };
      })
      .onUpdate((event) => {
        translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
        translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
      })
      .onEnd(() => {
        if (translateY.value > -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) {
          scrollTo(0);
        } else if (translateY.value < -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1.5) {
          scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        }
      });

    const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      const borderRadius = interpolate(
        translateY.value,
        [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + 50, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
        [25, 5],
        Extrapolate.CLAMP
      );

      return {
        borderRadius,
        transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
      };
    });

    return (
      <View>
        <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.bottomSheetContainer, rBottomSheetStyle]}>
            <View style={styles.line} />
            {children}
          </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
    );
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomSheetContainer: {
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    borderRadius: 25,
  },
  line: {
    width: 75,
    height: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginVertical: 15,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
});

export default BottomSheet;
```

List Component:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list'

const List = () => {
    const data = [
        { id: '1', title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: '2', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '3', title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: '243', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '14dff3', title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: '2564ewe36', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '24ere3', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '14drereff3', title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: '25erer6436', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '24rereer3', title: 'Item 2' },
        { id: '14dferrf3', title: 'Item 1' },
        { id: '2564er36', title: 'Item 2' }
    ];

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, maxHeight: '80%', }}>
                <FlashList
                    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                    data={data}
                    estimatedItemSize={100}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 37 }}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                                React Native
                            </Text>
                        </>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
        borderTopRightRadius: 40,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'gray',
        fontWeight: '500',
        fontSize: 14,
        left: 15,
        textAlign: 'left',
        width: '90%',
        marginBottom: 20
    },
})
export default List
```

Steps to reproduce
Take your mouse in the list and just Drag down the list it won't work on Andriod but works fine on iOS.

Gesture Handler version: 2.12.1

React Native version: 0.72.4

Platforms: Android

JavaScript runtime: Hermes

Workflow: React Native (without Expo)

Architecture: Fabric (New Architecture)

Build type: Debug mode

Device: Android emulator

Device model: Google Pixel 4

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the nested gestures, So what I did is `const gesture = Gesture.Pan().activeOffsetX([-10, 10])` and then add this to my GestureDetector `<GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>`

If you are using PanGestureHandler then do can simply do `<PanGestureHandler activeOffsetX={[-10, 10]}>`